# mapping 3 or more outputs on ffmpeg command

Tags: python-3.x, ffmpeg

I am using this below command to stream on multiple output it works fine till 2 outputs but when I added third output it's giving an error-

command for 2 output-

```
ffmpeg_stream = 'ffmpeg -thread_queue_size 1024 -f x11grab -draw_mouse 0 -s 1920x1080  -i :122 -f alsa -i pulse -ac 2 -c:a aac -b:a 64k -threads 0 -flags +global_header -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -s 1920x1080 -threads 0 -f tee -map 0:0 -map 1:0 "[f=flv]rtmps://live-api-s.facebook.com:443/rtmp/stream_key|[f=flv]rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/stream_key"'
```

command for 3 outputs-

```
ffmpeg_stream = 'ffmpeg -thread_queue_size 1024 -f x11grab -draw_mouse 0 -s 1920x1080  -i :122 -f alsa -i pulse -ac 2 -c:a aac -b:a 64k -threads 0 -flags +global_header -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -s 1920x1080 -threads 0 -f tee -map 0:0 -map 1:0 -map 2:0 "[f=flv]rtmps://live-api-s.facebook.com:443/rtmp/stream_key|[f=flv]rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/stream_key|[f=flv]rtmp://play.stream.some_domain/stream/i48b-rdq0-jwme-2yj0"'
```

error-

```
liveStreaming   | Invalid input file index: 2.
```

error with custom rtmp url only-

```
liveStreaming   | [rtmp @ 0x55af7e7f8280] Server error: Already 

publishing
liveStreaming   | [tee @ 0x55af7e12f540] Slave '[f=flv]rtmp://stream.domain/stream/i48b-rdq0-jwme-2yj0': error opening: Operation not permitted
liveStreaming   | [tee @ 0x55af7e12f540] Slave muxer #1 failed, aborting.
liveStreaming   | [flv @ 0x55af7e4d1880] Failed to update header with correct duration.
liveStreaming   | [flv @ 0x55af7e4d1880] Failed to update header with correct filesize.
liveStreaming   | Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Operation not permitted
liveStreaming   | Error initializing output stream 0:1 -- 
liveStreaming   | [aac @ 0x55af7e1346c0] Qavg: -nan
liveStreaming   | [alsa @ 0x55af7e111dc0] Thread message queue blocking; consider raising the thread_queue_size option (current value: 8)
liveStreaming   | Conversion failed!
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`-map` is used to add input streams for output. You have only 2 inputs. For the 3rd output using `tee`, you just need to add it inside the output URL like you already did. Remove `-map 2:0`

`ffmpeg_stream = 'ffmpeg -thread_queue_size 1024 -f x11grab -draw_mouse 0 -s 1920x1080  -i :122 -f alsa -i pulse -ac 2 -c:a aac -b:a 64k -threads 0 -flags +global_header -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -s 1920x1080 -threads 0 -f tee -map 0:0 -map 1:0 "[f=flv]rtmps://live-api-s.facebook.com:443/rtmp/stream_key|[f=flv]rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/stream_key|[f=flv]rtmp://play.stream.some_domain/stream/i48b-rdq0-jwme-2yj0"'`

Comment: hey, I appreciate your help. It is working with all the rtmp urls except a custom rtmp url. I figured I need to add `-flvflags no_duration_filesize` but I was not able make it work with tee command.

Comment: You have to add it inside the options for that output: `[f=flv:flvflags=no_duration_filesize]`